# Chromedriver times out after login

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, ui-testing

I am trying to run UI tests on Selenium. The website runs on SSL. When using Chromedriver, after login, the page keeps on loading and shows "Establishing secure connection" and then eventually times out. Chrome also shows the yellow triangle before the URL in the browser. However, I don't see the yellow triangle when I log into the website using Chrome outside of this. I further noticed that the standard settings in Chrome are not the same as the Chrome instance that opens up when Chromedriver fires it, not sure why.

[image: Screenshot showing the yellow triangle and the "establishing secure connection" message at bottom]

Can someone tell me what might be going on here and how I can fix the issue?

Comment: You need to try out with default chrome profile

Comment: It would help if you could add a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

It may be chromedriver issue. Try to downgrade it. Version 2.12 helped us with similar problem.
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads